# Iterate through list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of dictionaries in python with the following form:

```
[{'item_value': 0.1, 'date': datetime.datetime(2017, ...), 'item_index': 1.0}, 
{'item_value': 0.22, 'date': datetime.datetime(2016, ...), 'item_index': 0.1}, 
{'item_value': 0.21, 'date': datetime.datetime(2016, ...), 'item_index': 1.0}
 ,..., 
{'item_value': 1.03, 'date': datetime.datetime(2016, ...), 'item_index': 1.0}]
```

Variable **item_index** takes values: `[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, ..., 1.0]` while variable **item_value** values between [-1, 1]. I want to construct a numpy vector which contain all possible **item_index** with the most recent **item_value** using the date (by omitting duplicates with the same **item_value** and keeping the most recent ones).

I am using the proposed solution:

```
np.array([d["item_value"] for d in sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x["date"]))}
```

I create a numpy vector which contain all **item_values** sorted concerning the date `[1.03, 0.22, 0.21, 0.1]` in the case of the example. However,  I want to return a vector like the following example:

```
[0, 0.22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1]
```

Each position of vector to represent the 11 possible values for item_index and have as a value the most recent value of the item_value. How can I do so?

**EDIT**

One example can be:

```
[{'item_value': 0.0, 'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 11, 13, 39, 36, 979000), 'item_index': 1.0}
{'item_value': 0.0, 'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 11, 13, 40, 2, 368000), 'item_index': 1.0}
{'item_value': -1.0, 'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 23, 9, 35, 20, 741000), 'item_index': 1.0}
{'item_value': -1.0, 'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 23, 9, 35, 41, 915000), 'item_index': 0.8}
{'item_value': 0.0, 'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 23, 9, 36, 2, 763000), 'item_index': 0.5}
{'item_value': 0.0, 'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 23, 11, 40, 22, 427000), 'item_index': 1.0}
{'item_value': 0.0, 'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 14, 7, 33, 9, 131000), 'item_index': 1.0}
{'item_value': 0.51, 'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 15, 12, 50, 25, 14000), 'item_index': 1.0}
{'item_value': 0.0, 'date': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 19, 14, 15, 46, 761000), 'item_index': 1.0}
{'item_value': -0.49, 'date': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 19, 14, 16, 30, 207000), 'item_index': 1.0}
{'item_value': -0.009000000000000005, 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 19, 16, 32, 30, 631000), 'item_index': 1.0}
{'item_value': 0.0, 'date': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 19, 16, 33, 19, 509000), 'item_index': 1.0}
{'item_value': 0.0, 'date': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 19, 16, 44, 59, 483000), 'item_index': 1.0}
{'item_value': -0.33299999999999996, 'date': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 19, 18, 13, 17, 67000), 'item_index': 1.0}
{'item_value': 1.0, 'date': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 19, 18, 13, 48, 443000), 'item_index': 1.0}
{'item_value': -0.33299999999999996, 'date': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 19, 18, 14, 22, 871000), 'item_index': 1.0}
{'item_value': 0.0, 'date': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 28, 11, 45, 48, 223000), 'item_index': 1.0}
{'item_value': 0.005000000000000003, 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 28, 11, 46, 7, 481000), 'item_index': 1.0}
{'item_value': 0.0, 'date': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 28, 11, 46, 27, 845000), 'item_index': 1.0}
{'item_value': 0.0, 'date': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 28, 11, 46, 50, 386000), 'item_index': 1.0}]
```

Comment: The item_index take values [0.0, 0.1, 0.2- 1.0]. So I want for each value of the item_index the most recent item_value using the date info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A oneliner could be as follows:

```
indexes = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]

my_filtered_lists = [sorted([d for d in my_list if d['item_index'] == i], 
                            key=lambda x: x["date"])
                        for i in indexes ]

result = [l[-1]['item_value'] if len(l)>0 else 0  for l in my_filtered_lists]
```

For each index you filter the list, and sort each filtered list as desired and get the `item_value`  of the last element.
If the data set is big enough, this could be a little memory demanding, since you are creating one extra list for each `item_idex`.

Tested with:

```
 my_list = [
{'item_value': 0.1, 'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 05, 01), 'item_index': 1.0}, 
{'item_value': 0.22, 'date': datetime.datetime(2016,05,01), 'item_index': 0.1}, 
{'item_value': 0.21, 'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 05, 01), 'item_index': 0.1},
{'item_value': 1.03, 'date': datetime.datetime(2016,05,01), 'item_index': 1.0}]
```

It returns: `[0, 0.21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1]` wich I understand is the expected output.

Comment: There is the case that i dont have a dictionary in my list for a specific item_index. Thus, I got the error list out of range.

Comment: How can I take into consideration that for some indexes I dont have any entry and just return 0?

Comment: Addapted to that.

Comment: It does not work. It return for my case a wrong output.

Comment: Tell me please an example of input and desired output.

Comment: I have the example input in edit, and the output: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, -1, 0, x] where x is the most recent value for the case of item_index = 1.0

Comment: But the code is working ok. In the example, the most recent entry for item_index=1.0 is `{'date': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 28, 11, 46, 50, 386000), 'item_value': 0.0, 'item_index': 1.0}` which has item_value=0.0.

Comment: Sorry you are right, my bad. Super thanks for the answer.

Comment: Glad to hear. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to create an intermediate `dict` `key -> value` only keeping the most up-to-date values:

```
d = dict()
for value in sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x["date"]):
   d[value['item_index']] = d[value['item_value']]
```

Another solution would be to convert the list to a pandas `DataFrame`, sort by date, group by `item_index` with the `last()` function to only keep the latest record of the dataframe.

Comment: I am getting an error with the proposed solution: keyError 0.0